# How to pass a method to a Hash#map

Tags: ruby, hashmap, hashtable

The code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
h = {a: 1}
def f args
  p args
end
h.map(&method(:f))
a.map(&method(:f))
h.map do |k,v|
  p [k,v]
end
```

The output:

```
[:a, 1]
1
2
3
[:a, 1]
```

Why can't I define `f` for a hash as follows?

```
def f k, v
  p [k, v]
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `map` takes a collection, performs an operation on each value, and returns the result.  Are you just trying to print out the values?

Comment: Apparently not. I was trying to just like you said perform an operation on each value. But that's not the point. How come `map` calls `&method(:f)` with one argument (`[:a, 1]`), but explicit block with two of them (`:a` and `1`)?

Comment: Good question for illustrating differences between procs and lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears, it must be some sort of implicit destructuring (or non-strict arguments handling), which works for `proc`s, but doesn't for `lambda`s:

```
irb(main):007:0> Proc.new { |k,v| p [k,v] }.call([1,2])
[1, 2]
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):009:0> lambda { |k,v| p [k,v] }.call([1,2])
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
        from (irb):9:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):9:in `call'
        from (irb):9
        from /home/yuri/.rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

But one can make it work:

```
irb(main):010:0> lambda { |(k,v)| p [k,v] }.call([1,2])
[1, 2]
=> [1, 2]
```

And therefore:

```
def f ((k, v))
  p [k, v]
end
```

So `Hash#map` always passes one argument.

**UPD**

> This implicit destructuring also happens in block arguments.
>
> ```
> names = ["Arthur", "Ford", "Trillian"]
> ids = [42, 43, 44]
> id_names = ids.zip(names)   #=> [[42, "Arthur"], [43, "Ford"], [44, "Trillian"]]
> id_names.each do |id, name|
>   puts "user #{id} is #{name}"
> end
> ```

http://globaldev.co.uk/2013/09/ruby-tips-part-2/

**UPD** Don't take me wrong. I'm not suggesting writing such code (`def f ((k, v))`). In the question I was asking for explanation, not for the solution.

Comment: lambda is more strict than proc, actually that's one of the few differences between `lambda` and `proc`. To get the first example working, you would have to splat the arguments as you will normally would when calling a method with two arguments. `lambda { |k,v| p [k,v] }.call(*[1,2])`

Comment: when you do `lambda { |(k,v)| p [k,v] }.call([1,2])` you are creating a proc that accept only one argument but now you are applying a splat in the arguments. try this: `lambda { |(k,v)| p [k,v] }.call(1)`

Comment: splat is somewhat rare in Ruby, but it's a well defined behaviour and easy to understand once you study it. Check this link http://jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the reason stems from the one of the two main differences between `proc`'s and `lambda`'s. I'll trying explaining it in a slightly different way than you did.

Consider:

```
a = [:a, 1]
h = {a: 1}
def f(k,v)
  p [k, v]
end

a.each(&method(:f))
  #-> in `f': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
h.each(&method(:f))
  #-> in `f': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

where I use `#->` to show what is printed and `#=>` to show what is returned. You used `map`, but `each` is more appropriate here, and makes the same point.

In both cases elements of the receiver are being passed to the block<sup>1</sup>:

```
&method(:f)
```

which is (more-or-less, as I will explain) equivalent to:

```
{ |k,v| p [k,v] }
```

The block is complaining (for both the array and hash) that it is expecting two arguments but receiving only one, and that is not acceptable.  "Hmmm", the reader is thinking, "why doesn't it disambiguate in the normal way?"

Let's try using the block directly:

```
a.map { |k,v| p [k,v] }
  #-> [:a, nil]
  #   [1, nil]
h.map { |k,v| p [k,v] }
  #-> [:a, 1]
```

This works as expected, but does not return what we wanted for the array.
The first element of `a` (`:a`) is passed into the block and the block variables are assigned:

```
k,v = :a
  #=> :a 
k #=> :a 
v #=> nil
```

and

```
p [k,v]
  #-> :a
  #-> nil
```

Next, `1` is passed to the block and `[1,nil]` is printed.

Let's try one more thing, using a proc created with [Proc::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-c-new):

```
fp = Proc.new { |k,v| p [k, v] }
  #=> #<Proc:0x007ffd6a0a8b00@(irb):34>
fp.lambda?
  #=> false

a.each { |e| fp.call(e) }
  #-> [:a, nil]
  #-> [:a, 1] 
h.each { |e| fp[e] }
  #-> [:a, 1]
```

(Here I've used one of three aliases for [Proc#call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call).) We see that calling the `proc` has the same result as using a block. The `proc` expects two arguments and but receives only one, but, unlike the `lambda`, does not complain<sup>2</sup>.

This tells us that we need to make small changes to `a` and `f`:

```
a = [[:a, 1]]
h = {a: 1}
def f(*(k,v))
  p [k, v]
end

a.each(&method(:f))
  #-> [:a, 1] 
h.each(&method(:f))
  #-> [:a, 1]
```

Incidentally, I think you may have fooled yourself with the variable name `args`:

```
def f args
  p args
end
```

as the method has a single argument regardless of what you call it. :-)

<sup>1 The block is created by `&` calling [Method#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Method.html#method-i-to_proc) on the method `f` and then converting the proc (actually a lambda) to a block.</sup>

<sup>2 From the docs for [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html): "For procs created using lambda or ->() an error is generated if the wrong number of parameters are passed to a Proc with multiple parameters. For procs created using Proc.new or Kernel.proc, extra parameters are silently discarded."</sup>

Comment: `h.each(&method(:f))   #-> in \`f': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)` wrong, it outputs `[:a, 1]`; so `each` and `map` here are not particularly interchangeable; supposedly because `each` is redefined in `Hash` as opposed to `map` `Incidentally, I think you may have fooled yourself with the variable name args` not really, it was a way to make the code work